# Django/Python Web Scraping - the targeted tag isn't being found to pull the information I need

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, django-views, web-applications

I am working on a Django web application for sports cards. Each card has their own page that displays the card name at the top, and underneath it should display the current lowest price of that card. The lowest price value is pulled from https://cardboard.market/. In my views.py I want a function that gets this lowest price. Here is where I am at currently:

views.py:

def get_lowest_card_price(card_name):
base_url = "https://cardboard.market/"
search_url = f"{base_url}search?q={card_name}"

```
try:
    # Send a GET request to the website
    response = requests.get(search_url)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for bad responses (4xx or 5xx)

    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the element with the specified class
    target_div = soup.find('div', class_='bubble-element Text cmgaCs')

    # Extract the text content
    if target_div:
        price_text = target_div.text.strip()
        return price_text
    else:
        print(f"Could not find the specified div element for card '{card_name}'.")
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error during request: {e}")

return None
```

def ProSet1990_1(request):
# Hardcoded card details for demonstration purposes
card_name = "David Seaman"
card_set = "1990 Pro Set"

```
# Use the web scraping bot to get the lowest card price
lowest_price = get_lowest_card_price(f'{card_set} {card_name}')

# Pass the data to the template
context = {
    'card_name': card_name,
    'lowest_price': lowest_price,
}

# Render the template with the data
return render(request, 'Application/ProSet1990_1.html', context)
```

**When I run my server and go to the html page for the card, my cmd prompt displays "Could not find the specified div element for card '1990 Pro Set David Seaman'."**

I have checked that the tag matches on the site for it to pull the card's price. If anyone has any ideas please let me know! Thank you!